# Is it beneficial to include non UX related research on a portfolio?

Tags: research, portfolio

I'm a psychology undergrad and I've done a number of research papers, but not much has to do with UX, though a few (not all) have to to with HCI and the sociology of social media.

Comment: If you do include it, be sure to describe what you did in terms that will be meaningful to your *current* readers. Don't expect potential employers or colleagues to be able to work out the relevance of your research to UX, even if it's clear to you. If your work is in a field particularly distant from UX (clinical interventions, animal research), also focus on the transferrable skills that you used, not just the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is very beneficial as it demonstrates you can do your own user research. I would insert it below the primarily relevant information under the "Additional skills: User research etc".

NB: I mostly operate in Europe, so the standard and mentality may differ.